# How to Create a Request and Response objects in Java-Spark microservice framework?

Tags: java, request, spark-java

There is a scenario which I'm currently facing where I have to manually create an instance of the `spark.Request` & `spark.Response`object. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am creating both request and response objects for testing purposes.

My implementation looks like this

```
package spark;

public class RequestStub extends Request {
    // Implement the methods needed
    // I fake my return values
}
```

This works well for testing.

If this isn't what you need, then please share more details and perhaps a code sample to describe your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. What I want is to not make a REST call but a normal procedure call with Request and Response objects something like: `new ControllerClass().restServiceMethod('<my request obect>','<my response obect>')`

Comment: What I mean is how will I update request.body with the help of stub.

Comment: I haven't done anything like that. I am unsure if you do that easily. I would start by looking at the source for Sparkjava to see if I could find a seam that could be used.

Comment: Thanks for the response Thomas, I will try to look if there is an alternative for this...If you even find something please update me.Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In your derived classes you can override body() body(String text), status(), status(int stat) etc - all the methods you need. Like this for the Request body say...

```
class RequestStub extends Request
{
    private String _body;

    RequestStub(String body)
    {
        _body = body;
    }

    public String body()
    {
        return _body;
    }
}
```

So you get to do something like this...

```
Request rq  = new RequestStub(readFile("./src/test/resources/nested-test.txt"));
Response rp = new ResponseStub();

String result = (String)Controller.Post.handle(rq,rp);
```